In the simulate_tweedie function of R, what is weight? I understand that ancillary is rho i.e., the dispersion parameter
I need to understand this example code :
library(GlmSimulatoR)
library(ggplot2)
library(cplm, quietly = TRUE)
set.seed(1)

simdata <- simulate_tweedie(weight = 0.2, ancillary = 1.15, link = "log")

ggplot(simdata, aes(x = Y)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)

glm_model <- cpglm(Y ~ X1, data = simdata, link = "log")
summary(glm_model)

I need to develop a GLM between some repair time data I have for different levels of peak ground acceleration.

Good question, have you found the answer yet?
